# Complex analysis about Kramers-Kronig relation

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have an equation
\begin{equation}
|w-f(w+i\eta)|^2 = a^2
\end{equation}
where $w$ is a real variable, $a$ is a real given parameter and $\eta$ is an positive infinitesimal number.
The function $f(z)$ is analytical in the upper and lower complex plane (may have singularities along real axis), which means the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)$ satisfy Kramers-Kronig relations
\begin{equation}
\Re f(\omega) =  {1 \over \pi} \mathcal{P}\!\!\!\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty {\Im f(\omega') \over \omega' - \omega}\,d\omega'
\end{equation}

My question is that from the conditions given above, the $f(z)$ can, in principle, uniquely determined. However, how can I resolve it to get the explicit expression of $f(z)$? Thanks so much.

Comment: Is $w$ a specific value or does this hold for all $w$ in some set?

Comment: Hi, $w$ is a real variable defined on the real axis. $a$ is a given real parameter.

Comment: In that case how does $\eta$ work? Because if $w$ is a pole of $f$ by definition letting $\eta$ get arbitrarily small means the equality breaks down.

Comment: if $w$ is a pole, when $\eta$ getting smaller, $f(w+i\eta)$ becomes more likely a $\delta$ function. Actually, this problem originated from physics, specifically, the Green's function theory. $f(z)$, in general, is a Green's function, which is analytical both on upper and lower half plane, but may have poles or branch cuts along real axis.